# Will Apple reject an app that sole function is to view one bundled PDF?

Tags: ios, pdf, app-store, appstore-approval

I have a client who wants to create an iOS application that's sole purpose is to display one PDF.  Assuming the content of the PDF is purely innocuous, do people think Apple will accept an app wish such limited functionality?  I know Apple has rejected some apps for being too simplistic.  I'm a little worried that this might qualify.

Comment: Isn't that what the iBooks app is for?

Comment: why would you force the user to get an app from the app store rather than just giving them an actual PDF to view?

Comment: What does this app do differently than viewing the PDF stand-alone (assuming that viewing stand-alone PDFs is possible in iOS)? I suppose this app is just a dressed-up/themed/branded PDF viewer with content fixed to a single PDF?

Comment: @Stephen: My guess is it's a marketing thing.

Comment: Why not just use a web url for marketing and provide the information available through a website and/or a PDF.

Comment: I here you.  I've made the same exact points to this particular client.  They like the idea that they can send someone directly to a app store link even if it doesn't make a lot of sense for the users.  My last attempt to disuade them was that Apple would likely reject it.  But they wanted some evidence of this beyond my gut feeling.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if Apple *feels* that and app is of limited utility for it's users, the rejection is a possibility.

I've heard and red about several cases of this kind of behaviour. Also a friend of mine *suffered* from this criteria.

I'm not discussing the validity and usefulness of your app, I'm just saying that it is a possibility that an app can be rejected if it has a limited utility.